# View is pushed down by about 20px, but is fixed when I rotate screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller(Nib) that is invoked from two different places. When I invoke it from one place, all looks fine but from the other it always seems to have a 20px(looks like enough for the status bar) offset up top..

If I rotate the device this goes away and it looks OK..I've been troubleshooting this since yesterday with no luck - As far as I can tell I'm not doing anything different when I load the screen..

I'm not really sure what code to paste, as from both places they are being called in the same way, I'm looking for any ideas - even if it's not an answer as I seem to be out of ideas.

Screenshot,

[image]

Comment: Show the view code as it could be something in the `viewDidLoad` / `viewDidAppear` etc. Also are you playing with the window at all??

Comment: What is the view's `autoresizingMask`? Or, if you're using autolayout, its top-distance-to-parent constraint value.

Comment: Fixed:

The one that was presenting the VC wrong was actually a child of the child of the main view controller. When I presented it from the parent's parent it works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting `edgesForExtendedLayout` in `viewDidLoad`?

```
if ( IS_OS_7_OR_LATER && [self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)] ) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

**EDIT**: here is the [iOS 7 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html) from Apple if you want more info on how this is fixed for iOS 7

Comment: I did try that and got the same results. My only thought right now is that it's being caused by the viewController that is calling it, because once it gets into the new viewcontroller, the code being called is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that these questions will help us and you to pinpoint the problem:

1. Are you invoking the VC using Interface builder or programmatically?
2. Have you added any or none constraints?

My best guess would be that you try to load the VC from:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

rather then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

The reason for this suggestion is that the screen bounds are not properly loaded in viewDidLoad which you can check by printing `self.view.bounds.width` & `self.view.bounds.height`. In viewDidLoad they are not set correctly. This can lead to many later problems. This is just a wild guess.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am invoking programmatically. No constraints, it is not using autolayout.. Even if I use autolayout I get the same result. I'll check the bounds..